# How to monitor CPU credits and CPU balance for an instance with multiple vCPUs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

his is a chart of the CPU utilization, and the CPUCredit in my t3.small instance:

[image]

[According to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html#cpu-credits), an instance will only use CPU credits when the CPU utilization is above the baseline. If the instance has more than one vCPU, the baseline performance will be shown at the original level.

If I understand correctly, the instance should use CPU credits only when utilization is above 20%. In the chart, it seems like CPU credits are consumed even when the utilization is lower. **Why is that?**

Comment: Is the time resolution in above graph 1min and the aggregation method for `CPUUtilization` set to `Max`? If not, can you please post another graph with the mentioned settings!?

Comment: Thanks @Dunedan, once I changed the aggregation method to `Max` the chart made sense. If you post an answer i'll accept. Thank :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph in your answer shows the average CPU utilization per time period. For the calculation of CPU credit usage however it's relevant how the maximum CPU utilization per minute looks like. Therefore if you change the aggregation method of your CPU utilization from average to maximum you should see a graph which makes more sense.